# How can I group by a foreign key but return the foreign object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I've been working with EF for quite some time but I always come across these kinds of statements

```
.GroupBy(movies => movies.Category) //Category is a foreign object
```

And normally I wouldn't want this kind of line in my code because you're never quite sure by what the object compares to. But if I try to group by the foreign key like

```
.GroupBy(movies => movies.CategoryId) //CategoryId is the EF generated foreign key
```

I never get the object which I sometimes need in the result of the query. I've already looked at some other overrides of the GroupBy function but it seems to me that all of them return the key in some way.
One thing I tried was creating an anon object.

```
.GroupBy(movies => new {movies.CategoryId, movies. Category})
```

But it threw an EF exception.

So I've been using the first statement based on the assumption that EF translates it into a statement which groups by ID like this. Does it really? Or is there some overload or trick I could use to make sure that I group by the Id?

Comment: Tried this? `.GroupBy(n => n.CategoryId).ToDictionary(n => n.Key, n => n.ToArray());`

Comment: 1. I would like to do the rest on the server and not in a dictionary on the client

2. It would still select the key and not the object itself

Comment: Can't you check the generated SQL, to see what happens ? Have a look and you are sure.